# Freepbx data integration with custom CRM

Tags: asterisk, crm

NET experts,

I have a scenario where a 4-port PSTN card is installed in a server and I have installed Freebpx on that server as per suggestion by someone. When a call comes on any of the PSTN line, it is forwarded to one of the operators on his hard phone.

Each operator is also having a computer screen at his table, powered by an individual CPU. This runs our CRM software to be handled by operator. When a call arrives to an operator hard phone, say operator 2, we want that the Caller number should also be displayed in the CRM software. Based on this caller number, operator can enter some information related to the Caller and save it in database via our CRM software. Also, when operator disconnect the call, we should receive call stop time for statistics later on.

Thus, we need caller number and call start time when a call is picked by an operator on his hard phone. and then we need call end time when a call is finished.

Can someone help us how we can achieve this? Do we have to capture the SIP packets and parse them or their is some other way to do so? Our CRM database is totally separate from the Freepbx and resides on another server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get these events realtime, you should look at AMI (Asterisk Manager Interface - port 5038 TCP by default) and it's configuration manager.conf (note: FreePBX uses the, see manager_custom.conf).

If you want the archived version, you should set up a database server, and point the CDR (Call Detail Records) module to it. PostgreSQL or MySQL/MariaDB works just fine. Asterisk will simply ignore additional fields in the CDR as long as they can be NULL or has a DEFAULT value. This can be used to store custom data.

Comment: I tried connecting to the Asterisk server via the AMI on 5038 port and it replies with the status of the code. But when a call comes, it doesn't send this information to my C# sample project. 

If somehow, I can get the information in my C# application with Caller id and operator who has picked it, I can query my own database (another machine than the Asterisk one) to fetch the caller information or use the caller number to store a new record in my own database.

Comment: You need to enable CEL (Channel Event Logging) events for the AMI (Manager) interface by adding the follwoing lines to /etc/asterisk/cel.conf

Comment: [general]
enable = yes
apps = dial,hangup,transfer
events = ALL

[manager]
enabled = yes